# Microsoft PowerAutomate - Get current quarter

Tags: power-automate

I want to get the current quarter so I can put it in the email subject.
Is there an expression in Microsoft Power Automate for this, I can't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking of the "year quarter" (ie: Q1 for January, February, March, Q2 for April, May, June, etc.), there is no built-in function but several ways to calculate this value.

A classical one is to divide the month by 3, and round the value to the upper integer, but round function is not available in Power Automate...

I found another way:

```
concat('Q', add(div(sub(##MyMonthVariableAsInt##),1), 3), 1))
```

For example, if your date input is the current UTC date, that would be the following:

```
concat('Q', add(div(sub(int(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'MM')),1), 3), 1))
```